# Convert 3D CBCT dicom to 2D Panaromic View

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, 2d, rendering

I want to generate 2D panarmoic view from the series of 3D cbct dental images by python.

I am converting the series of 3D Cbct images to 2D panaromic view by python. The code is working fine but the output is not complete.

```
import sys
import vtkmodules.all as vtk
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from vtkmodules.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor

def create_reader(dir):
    
    reader = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
    reader.SetDirectoryName(dir)
    reader.Update()
    
    return reader

def create_center(reader):
    
    (xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax, zMin, zMax) = reader.GetExecutive().GetWholeExtent(reader.GetOutputInformation(0))
    (xSpacing, ySpacing, zSpacing) = reader.GetOutput().GetSpacing()
    (x0, y0, z0) = reader.GetOutput().GetOrigin()
    
    center = [x0 + xSpacing * 0.5 * (xMin + xMax),
            y0 + ySpacing * 0.5 * (yMin + yMax),
            z0 + zSpacing * 0.5 * (zMin + zMax)]
    
    return center

def create_sagittal_slice_matrix(center):
    
    #Create Sagittal Slice Matrix
    sagittal = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
    sagittal.DeepCopy((0, 0, -1, center[0],
                        1, 0, 0, center[1],
                        0, -1, 0, center[2],
                        0, 0, 0, 1))
    
    return sagittal
    
    
def create_resliced_image(reader, sagittal, frame):
    
    # Reslice image
    widget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(frame)
    slice = vtk.vtkImageReslice()
    slice.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
    slice.SetOutputDimensionality(2)
    slice.SetResliceAxes(sagittal)
    slice.SetInterpolationModeToLinear()
    
    return widget, slice

def create_display_image_actor(slice):    
    
    # Display the image
    actor = vtk.vtkImageActor()
    actor.GetMapper().SetInputConnection(slice.GetOutputPort())
    # renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    
    return actor
        
def adjust_renderer_settings(renderer, widget, actor):

    # Remove Renderer And Reset
    renderer.RemoveAllViewProps()
    renderer.ResetCamera()
    widget.GetRenderWindow().Render()
    renderer.AddActor(actor)

    widget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(renderer)
    
    return widget

def setup_interaction(widget):
    # Set up the interaction
    slice_interactorStyle = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleImage()
    slice_interactor = widget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()
    slice_interactor.SetInteractorStyle(slice_interactorStyle)
    widget.GetRenderWindow().SetInteractor(slice_interactor)
    widget.GetRenderWindow().Render()
    
    return slice_interactor
    # Start interaction
    # slice_interactor.Start()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
 
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
 
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.vl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        reader = create_reader(r"C:\work.ateeb\2.16.840.114421.10241.9572018034.9603554034\DECOMPRESSED\One")
        center = create_center(reader)
        sagittal = create_sagittal_slice_matrix(center)
        
        self.vtkWidget, slice = create_resliced_image(reader, sagittal, self.frame)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)
        
        # create renderer
        renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        
        # create actor
        actor = create_display_image_actor(slice)  
        
        self.vtkWidget = adjust_renderer_settings(renderer, self.vtkWidget, actor)  
    
        slice_interactor = setup_interaction(self.vtkWidget)
        self.show()
        
        self.frame.setLayout(self.vl)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        
        slice_interactor.Initialize()
        slice_interactor.Start()

 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 
    window = MainWindow()
 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I was expecting the output like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IciD.png)

But the output the code is generating is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gofyu.png)

Comment: well...actually it looks much expected to me - a saggital reconstruction of an axial CT. I do not think that slicing is the approach to go here. What you probably want to do is a summation of all planes using a coronal projection plane.

Comment: Thank you Kritzel_sw for replying.

Can you please guide, how can I proceed futher ?

Comment: I am reluctant to advise on how to create an x-ray (=projection) image from a stack of slices.  TBH, I do not know if this is possible at all. But I think the closest match will be achieved by reconstructing a stack of coronal reconstructions. The slice distance can be the x-dimension of the axial images. Then iterate through the coronal slices and sum all pixel values at the same (x,y) position. This will exceed the grayscale range of course. So as a final step, you should normalize the pixel values of the resulting image by dividing through (max possible output value / max sum value)

Comment: Thanks again Kritzel_sw for guidence, I have reached at the 2nd last step (step K) of the research paper I have followed. https://www.frontiersin.org/files/Articles/545647/fbioe-08-00794-HTML/image_m/fbioe-08-00794-g001.jpg. 
I am stuck on step K. Donot now how to go at last step (Generate Panaromic View). Can you please help

Comment: I also don't know. I would probably go for integrating the pixel values that are on planes perpendicular to the curve. But I don't know how to make sure that it does not run too far into the volume and include pixels from the opposite side of the jaw. That probably needs some heuristics...